# React Native <{}> syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I created a new React Native project using `react-native init` and in the generated template, the main component class looks like this:

```
export default class App extends Component<{}> {
   ...
}
```

I don't really understand what the `<{}>` part means. I've never seen this before and all the examples seem to omit it. Just curious as to what its purpose is and if it's necessary.

Answer (score 2):

When you are using typescript, you have to specify the type of values to be expected. This allows detecting mismatching properties during compile time and reduces the amount of errors.

So when you do `Component<{}>`, `{}` is the type for `Props`, your component will receive.

This is how React's [Component](https://github.com/Quramy/tsc-react-example/blob/master/typings/react/react.d.ts#L117) class looks like:

[image]

If you notice, the type is `<P, S>`, which stands for `<Props, State>`.

---

There is another interface called [ComponentClass](https://github.com/Quramy/tsc-react-example/blob/master/typings/react/react.d.ts#L153) that has a signature `<P>`,

[image]

which initializes a new component internally with state as `any`. This interface is used in [ReactElement's type](https://github.com/Quramy/tsc-react-example/blob/master/typings/react/react.d.ts#L11):

[image]

So all in all, you are defining a Component which accepts no props and but can have state of any type. This is usually done when you are not sure about you component's interactions.

Ideally a component should look like this:

```js
interface IComponentState {
  ...
}

interface IComponentProps {
  ...
}

export class MyComponent<IComponentProps, IComponentState> extends React.Component {
  ...
}
```

This enforces consumer to pass any necessary properties and enforces you to have proper value of state.

Comment: however, react native files have a `js` extension, not `ts`

Answer (score 0):

This is either Typescript of Flow. You usually don't describe props as propTypes, but rather as interface or type. Then the type is passed to React.Component as a generic.

Type of props would be the passed type plus `{ children?: ReactNode }`

Actually there are two generic arguments, second for State

Very useful and convenient stuff.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html
https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react-&-webpack.html

Answer (score 0):

These are flow type annotations. See https://flow.org/
You'll notice that there's a `@flow` comment at the top of the file, and a `.flowconfig` file in the root of the project.

Using flow here is optional, but it can help you catch bugs.